# The most people/most people

Tags: adjectives

These are correct:

> **Most people agree on this.**
>
> **Most of the people agree on this.**

This is said to be wrong:

> **The most people agree on this.**

But I come across "the most people" which are considered correct.

> Some people agree on X, more people agree on Y, but *the most people*
> agree on Z.
>
> However, if we go beyond the original question of what is “proper”
> into what will most easily be understood *by the most people*.

What's the key to understanding the difference?

Comment: Assertion #1 *The word "okay" will be understood by the most people* is perfectly valid, but it doesn't actually mean exactly the same as #2 *The word "okay" will be understood by most people* without that definite article. #1 means that of all words in all languages, *"okay"* is understood by more people than any other word (even if far less than 50% of all the people in the world understand it). But #2 unequivocally asserts that at least 50% of all people will understand it.

Comment: ...and your example *Some people agree on X, more people agree on Y, but the most people agree on Z* sounds fine to me. Per my previous comment, including ***the*** affects the meaning.

Comment: Is this also correct "The most people who has this phone are satisfied with it"?

Comment: The most people = The largest number of people.  Most People = The majority of people.

Comment: Examples: Of all the countries in the EU, Germany has the most people (the largest number of people).  However, most people (the majority of people) in the EU do not live in Germany.

Comment: Also note that "people" is plural.  So it's "people have" not "has".

Comment: I was told that this is correct "1 Most people who have this phone are satisfied with it." but this is wrong "2 The most people who have this phone are satisfied with it." Is 2 really wrong?

Comment: 2 is really wrong.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. NGrams is case-sensitive, so [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Most+people+think+that%2CThe+most+people+think+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows only *sentences* starting with ***Most people think that** [the Moon is made of green cheese, or whatever].* Where it's important to note that there are effectively ***no*** written instances of such sentences starting with the definite article. ***The** most people think [something]* simply isn't a credible utterance in English.

Comment: Usage: The fewest people agree on this; the most people agree on this. It depends on context!

Comment: Lambie, clear as mud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Most people agree on this**, the meaning of **most** is 'the majority of people'.

In **Some people agree on X, more people agree on Y, but the most people agree on Z**, the meaning of **the most** is 'the largest group'. The sentence is comparing three groups of people rather than referring to one large group.

Answer (score 0):

There is implied information which is literally missing from the second sentence. For example:
Most of the people (whom I've spoken to) agree on this.

We use "of" to show that the people we are referring to belong to the group we have implied.

Without using "of" we are referring to people as a whole, not a specific set of people.

Most (of the) people (in the world) agree with this.

Otherwise, we don't know which people we refer to. Why have we included the word "the" at the beginning of the sentence? It only makes us wonder what is missing, such as in your correct example talking about two other groups of people: some agreeing about x, and more agreeing about y. Relative to these other two groups, we can include the final "but the most people agree on z.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry you can't understand my answer. I'm amazed at how against communication you are in a language learning community. :(